# Research on how to teach math to children - what proven approaches are there to teaching math effectively?

Tags: secondary-education, mathematical-pedagogy, reference-request, general-pedagogy, teaching

I posted a related question on the Math.SE, but was directed here where I'm asking an similar but different question.

I've been tasked with helping to redesign a math curriculum for an enrichment program and I have very few restrictions on what the curriculum should include or how it should flow. The curriculum is meant to be an enrichment curriculum (supplementary to the existing one here in Ontario).

I wanted to find some resources on proven and effective ways to design and teach math so that students have a deeper, more rigorous and more intuitive understanding of math - an approach that prepares them to tackle math abstractly and ultimately prepares them for higher level math. The curriculum starts at grade 4 and continues on to grade 11.

I'm aware this is a broad topic, but where can I start to get information that hasn't been contradicted or proven to not be effective?

Comment: I think asking for introductory texts on the subject is okay, though the question in the title is too broad.

Comment: @TommiBrander I think this question can be improved into a really great question, and if Stack Exchange had a communite of members with a really good technique of interaction, this question would have been located, improved, and gotten a lot of attention. Maybe the question https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/15475/is-the-education-system-in-finland-particularly-good also would get a lot of attention because they could tell that another question like this question could exist and be worth a lot of attention after that question gets an answer, even if this question

Comment: didn't already exist.

Comment: I think it's clear enough what this question is. Just because it's not clear to you what the question is doesn't mean it's not clear to anyone. I think it was explained clearly enough for those who have the ability to understand what it's saying. I don't see how the author could possibly figure out how to make it better. People learn through answers to their own past questions how to make future questions clearer. How is the author of this question going to learn if this question is closed after it got not even one answer?